# nested ng-repeat on Object (not with Array object)

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Issue: Always getting ***"[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater:"*** error on console while doing ng-repeat on object (looping with (key,value) pairs and again taking value as another object and nested looping through as below, tried with "track by $index" and also tried with external indexing(added variable to each object with incremental value)

Can some one please help me to fix console error?
Attached sample code snapshot.
[image]

Comment: [Where is your code?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Mukyuu, attached screenshot, please have a look.

Comment: Do your objects have unique ids? maybe you can try to `track by key` in your first repeat and `track by key1`in your second.